# как в ansible заменить строку по регулярному выражению

Tags: регулярные-выражения, ansible

Для работы со строками есть replace и lineinfile, но они позволяют полностью удалить строку при обнаржении шаблона, а replace дает заменить вхождения шаблона(но не всю строку). Т.е. получается сначала удалить все обнаружонные строки, а потом вставить нужную в нужном месте через linеinfile.
А как вот чтобы одним действием?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- name: Замена с обратными ссылками
  lineinfile:
    path: some.conf
    regexp: '^(.*)match(.*)$'
    line: '\1replacement\2'
    backrefs: yes
```

[Документация](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html)